# Как исправить ссылку?

Tags: phpmyadmin, get, php, mysql

Такой вот запрос,

```
$month = $_GET['month'];
$day = $_GET['day'];
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM client WHERE month = "'.$month.'" and day = "'.$day.'"') or die (mysql_error()); 
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){  
print"<br><b>Результат:</b> <a href=../index.php?option=content&task=view&id=".$r['url'].">".$r['name']."</a>";
}
```

Результат, думаю, Вам понятен. `client.php?month=1&day=22` выводит имена клиентов за январь месяц 22 число, и так же ссылки из столбца `url` таблицы `client`. А как сделать так, чтоб в случае отсутствия ссылки на клиента, код a `href` не ставился? То есть было просто имя без ссылок?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Элементарную проверку на "пустоту" сделать.

```
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    if($r['url'] != ''){
        $link = '../index.php?option=content&task=view&id='.$r['url'];
    } else {
        $link = '#';
    }
    echo '<p><strong>Результат:</strong><a href="'.$link.'">'.$r['name'].'</a></p>';
}
```

Comment: Думаю с точки зрения юзабилити, чтоб не обнадеживать пользователя ссылкой типа <a href="#'></a>, исправить:
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
echo '<p><strong>Результат:</strong>';
    if($r['url'] != ''){
        $link = '../index.php?option=content&task=view&id='.$r['url'];
echo '<a href="'.$link.'">'.$r['name'].'</a></p>';
    } else {
        echo $r['name'].'</p>';
    }
}